# Multi model sign up with clearance in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, clearance

So I want to create a Company while signing up as a new user to my application. I use https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance for authentication.

I have these 2 migrations:

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.attachment :logo

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And

```
class CreateClearanceUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :encrypted_password, limit: 128, null: false
      t.string :confirmation_token, limit: 128
      t.string :remember_token, limit: 128, null: false
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.attachment :avatar
      t.integer :company_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
    add_index :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

My models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Clearance::User

  belongs_to :company
end
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

This is my altered Clearance controller:

```
class Clearance::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :redirect_signed_in_users, only: [:create, :new]
  skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:create, :new]
  skip_before_filter :authorize, only: [:create, :new]

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_company

    render template: "users/new"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_back_or url_after_create
    else
      render template: "users/new"
    end
  end

  private

  def avoid_sign_in
    warn "[DEPRECATION] Clearance's `avoid_sign_in` before_filter is " +
      "deprecated. Use `redirect_signed_in_users` instead. " +
      "Be sure to update any instances of `skip_before_filter :avoid_sign_in`" +
      " or `skip_before_action :avoid_sign_in` as well"
    redirect_signed_in_users
  end

  def redirect_signed_in_users
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to Clearance.configuration.redirect_url
    end
  end

  def url_after_create
    Clearance.configuration.redirect_url
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, companies_attributes: [:id, :name])
  end
end
```

And at last my form:

```
<div class="form-item">
  <%= form.label :first_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name, type: "text" %>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
  <%= form.label :last_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :last_name, type: "text" %>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email, type: "email" %>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
  <%= form.fields_for :companies do |builder| %>
    <label>Company</label>
    <%= builder.text_field :name, type: "text" %>
  <%end%>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
  <%= form.label :password %>
  <%= form.password_field :password %>
</div>
```

I can perfectly submit my form, but my company_id is nil when finding the user object in rails console.

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the singular:

```
= form.fields_for :company
```

and in your controller:

```
company_attributes # instead of companies_attributes
```

and you have one thing in the wrong model! You want to save a company with the user so you need to move `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to `user.rb`

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

Comment: That did not fix it sadly. Form submits tho.

Comment: Looks like the form is just refreshing now no longer creating the user. Maybe something wrong in my migrations?

Comment: Looks like I get an error now:

PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (3, Test company, null, null, null, null, null, 2015-07-08 19:37:39.640803, 2015-07-08 19:37:39.640803). : INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"

Comment: very good :)  so the user must fill in an email of the company too?

Comment: Had to remove the not null in my migrations :) It works now, thank you very much, wasn't far from a working version it seems!